# Oracle APEX Application Login Page Disappear instalty?

Tags: javascript, networking, oracle-apex

I have Deployed Oracle APEX Application In a bank which has many branches, I deployed the application in Main branch server and every thing is OK for all users using the application within the main branch connected to the server using LAN Network, **BUT** I have problem when other users in others Branches try to connect to the application : **The Problem Is:**

**The login page of application appear for only about 3 second and disappear instantly!..**

Any Help Please!..

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of this before.

1. What version of APEX is this?
2. What browser version are you using in the MAIN branch?
3. What browser version is being used by users in the other branches?
4. When the login page vanishes, if they try to view the source of the page (in their browser), is there any content there?

Joel

Comment: It was problem of the browser in the other branch. thank you.